# calling a json webservice from C using curl and json-c

Tags: c, json, web-services, curl

I need to call a restful webservice that accepts json object. 
I was able to find libraries like **libcurl** to call a webservice from C application. I was also able to find libraries like **json-c** to create a json object in C.

libcurl accepts a string and posts it to the given webservice url. Is there anyway that I can post the json object created by using json-c libraries and call the webservice using the curl libraries.

Please let me know if there is any other library that will allow me both, to create a json object and call a webservice or any other alternate solution.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: You should have no problem using those two libraries. Convert your json object to a string and include it in your curl request body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example using both libraries :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <json-c/json.h>

int  main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  /* LIB JSON-C PART */
    /* Create a JSON object */
    json_object * jObj = json_object_new_object();

    /* Create a string element */
    json_object *jString = json_object_new_string("Guybrush");

    /* Include the element to the JSON final object */
    json_object_object_add(jObj,"name", jString);


  /* LIB CURL PART */
    /* Initialize CURL */ 
    CURL *curlHandler = curl_easy_init();

    if(curlHandler) {
      /* Set CURL parameters */
      curl_easy_setopt(curlHandler, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.yoururl.com");
      curl_easy_setopt(curlHandler, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
      curl_easy_setopt(curlHandler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  
                json_object_to_json_string(jObj));

      /* Perform the request */ 
      CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curlHandler);

      /* Check for errors */ 
      if(res != CURLE_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "CURL failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

      /* Clean up */ 
      curl_easy_cleanup(curlHandler);
      json_object_object_del(jObj, "name");
      free(jObj);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function from json-c to convert your json object to a string and include this in the body of your curl request.

```
#include "json.h"

const char* json_object_to_json_string(struct json_object *obj);
```

Look [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html) for an example of a HTTP POST (you may need to use PUT or DELETE depending on the web service you are connecting to and what you want to do)